# Is there a Selenium wrapper to find element with a given selector type as an input (By.css_selector, By.xpath, By.class ...)?

Tags: python, selenium

Following methods are available in Python Selenium WebDriver to find multiple elements.
These methods will return list of elements.

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

I need ta wrapper ( a function) on top of those find_elements_by_xxxx in order to find any element given element with a given  selector type.

Comment: Can you give the example from real life that would be simplified if you have what you're asking for?

Comment: Not directly related to Robot Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most WebDriver implementations have a method `find_element` that takes in a `By` value and a selector value, which effectively does what Christine wrote.

```
driver = ...
driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css.selector")
```

The implementation in python's ChromeDriver looks like:

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
    """
    Find an element given a By strategy and locator. Prefer the find_element_by_* methods when
    possible.

    :Usage:
        element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')

    :rtype: WebElement
    """
    if self.w3c:
        if by == By.ID:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = '[id="%s"]' % value
        elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
        elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = ".%s" % value
        elif by == By.NAME:
            by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            value = '[name="%s"]' % value
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
        'using': by,
        'value': value})['value']
```

Comment: Why this comment is made in the ChromeDriver implementation:
""" Prefer the find_element_by_* methods when possible. """

Comment: My guess is that it make the code look cleaner? It looks like the `find_element_by_*` methods all call `find_element`.

Comment: You are right all of these methodes call find_element.
So It is  Only for readability and comprehensibility purposes ? ....

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a function that takes `By` as a parameter?

```
def find_elements_by(driver, by, locator):
    return driver.find_elemements(by, locator)
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
xpath_result = find_elements_by(driver, By.XPATH, "//input")

class_result = find_elements_by(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "className")

css_result = find_elements_by(driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css.selector")
```

You can change this up to make it static so you are just using `driver.find_elements_by(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css.selector")`

Comment: If you are downvoting this answer, please let me know how this can be improved to better answer the original poster's question. This code has been tested, and to my understanding, covers the original question that was asked -- any feedback is appreciated.